# Visualizing the output of a test on image processing code

Tags: ios, testing, image-processing, xctest

I have image processing tasks I want to test against fixed data and as a part of this, I would want to see the output. When I run a test with XCTest though, I cannot save an image to albums (doesn't error out, but doesn't save even) and from what I know I cannot stop the test and visualize something on screen. What is the approach in this case?

Comment: Would it be an option to post the resulting images to a server? Or perhaps write them out to an absolute path, as in `/Users/yourusername/Desktop/test.png`?

Comment: Can you do that if the test runs on the device? My code doesn't work on the simulator... server would be an option, but quite painful to maintain...

Comment: Nope. What about a server that runs on the attached Mac and receives files?

Comment: I guess. Is there any library that can help?

Comment: Nothing specific to this problem. You would have to build something with NSURLSession or AFNetworking or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I sent the images to a local Ruby on Rails server that saves them in a cache folder where I can access them.